# commercial bzr hosting, with trac?

Tags: hosting, trac, bazaar

I am looking for bzr hosting for a closed-source project. I need wiki, bug tracking and web code overview, preferably trac. What would you suggest?

Most commercial hostings don't have bzr, which I like; would I be better off switching to git then?

Comment: Belongs on webmasters more than here, not programming-related.

Comment: I expect answers from programmers who acually have work-experience with such hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any bzr hosting providers that offer trac. See http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/Hosting for a basic list of hosters.

That said, I'm not sure which hosters support git and provide trac support.

You are presumably after external hosting for a reason, but I should mention it is fairly easy to set up your own trac instance with bzr support.

Comment: I could be anything else than trac; but in general bzr hosting seems to be sparse, perhaps because launchpad is so dominant. I will probably go ahead and do it myself (not for the first time, anyway)... Thanks.